# SQL Table update based on values within table

Tags: t-sql

I am looking to update rows in a table with values from other rows on the same table based on a common value.
In the table below I need to update the rows where 'Effective', 'End' and 'Enddate' are blank with the values from the row with the same IRN and FRN and where Name='[FCA CF] Functions requiring qualifications'.

So row 1 would inherit the data from row 2, row 3 from row 4, etc.

How can I do that please?
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some sample input data that we can copy-paste and type out the expected result. The "_row 1 would inherit the data from row 2_" part of your question is confusing without sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a regular `update` statement with a self join should do it.

**Sample data**

```
create table data
(
  IRN int,
  FRN int,
  Name nvarchar(50),
  Effective bit,
  Ended bit,
  EndDate date
);

insert into data (IRN, FRN, Name, Effective, Ended, EndDate) values
(100, 200, 'Something else?',                             null, null, null),
(100, 200, '[FCA CF] Functions requiring qualifications', 1,    1,    '2020-12-06'),
(100, 200, 'Not what we are looking for',                 0,    0,    null),
(100, 300, 'Do not touch, different FRN',                 null, null, null);
```

**Solution**

```
update d1
set d1.Effective = d2.Effective,
    d1.Ended = d2.Ended,
    d1.EndDate = d2.EndDate
from data d1
join data d2
  on  d2.IRN = d1.IRN
  and d2.FRN = d1.FRN
where d1.Effective is null
  and d1.Ended is null
  and d1.EndDate is null
  and d2.Name = '[FCA CF] Functions requiring qualifications';
```

**Result**

```
IRN FRN Name                                        Effective Ended EndDate
--- --- ------------------------------------------- --------- ----- ----------
100 200 Something else?                             True      True  2020-12-06
100 200 [FCA CF] Functions requiring qualifications True      True  2020-12-06
100 200 Not what we are looking for                 False     False null
100 300 Do not touch, different FRN                 null      null  null
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1045ac1b072ebf0bfaa5ad6d7d6713e2) to see it in action.